# Base and child class function inheritance confusion (C++)

Tags: c++

I am very confused about base and child class function inheritance.
I have those classes:

```
#include <point.h>

class Polygon{
public:
    Polygon();
    virtual ~Polygon();
    void addPoint(Point *p);
    std::string getType();
    Point* getPoint(int index);
    int getNumOfPoints();
    int getColor();
    virtual int area()=0;

private:
  std::vector<Point*> _points;

  int color;
  std::string type = "Polygon";

};

class Rectangle : public Polygon{
public:
    Rectangle();
    virtual ~Rectangle();
    virtual int area();

private:
    std::vector<Point*> _points;

    int color;
    std::string type = "Rectangle";
};
```

Now, in the main I do this:

```
Rectangle rect();
rect.getType();
```

this gives me "Polygon" while I want "Rectangle"
I am quite sure I am confused with inheritance. So, according to how I understand, the base class functions get inherited, but why is it when I run the function it relates to the members of the object base class but not the actual object (Rectangle)?

Will be happy if someone would help!
Much appreciated

Comment: look up the difference between `private` and `protected` class access modifiers.

Comment: while you're at it, lookup how **polymorphism** works. once that sinks in, then make `getType()` a virtual member in both base and derived classes, and return the appropriate value for the class.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that `Rectangle::type` is completely unrelated to `Polygon::type`. It's a separate data member that just happens to have the same name.

One way to achieve the desired effect is by making `getType()` virtual and overriding it in every derived class:

```
class Polygon {
public:
    virtual std::string getType() = 0;
    ...
}

class Rectangle: public Polygon {
public:
    virtual std::string getType();
    ...
}

std::string Rectangle::getType() {
    return "Rectangle";
}
```

Comment: So, how do I design it that the child class inherits the functions but works actually on the CHILD CLASS members?

Comment: To achieve polymorphic behaviour, use virtual functions. See the expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two members named `type` in an instance of `Rectangle`. Since private members of `Polygon` are only accessible to the member functions of that class, it's as if they didn't exist when it comes to declaring members by the same name in `Rectangle`. It's not even shadowing proper, because in `Rectangle`, the `type` member of `Polygon` would not be accessible. So `Polygon::getType` returns the `type` defined in `Polygon` and not the unrelated one defined in `Rectangle`.

You have several ways to solve your issue:

- Define `type` as a protected member in `Polygon` and assign to it in every constructor.
- Drop `type`; declare `getType` as virtual and override it in every class, returning a constant string.
- Use RTTI for what it's good for: finding out the actual class of an object.
- Design your program so that you don't need to tell the exact type of an object. This is usually best. Every time you need different behavior for different subclasses of `Polygon`, write a virtual member function that implements the specific behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the type string in one place - your base class. Because you want it to be accessible in your derived classes but not to your user, make it protected. In each constructor, set it to the appropriate value:

```
Polygon::Polygon():
        type("polygon")
{}

Rectangle::Rectangle()
    Polygon()
{
    type = "rectangle";
}
```